# Kali Linux not detecting NIC interface

Tags: networking, wifi, kali-linux

I have Kali Linux imaged onto a USB which I boot from and use live mode. It runs fine but it doesn't connect to a network.

When I use  `ifconfig` it says I have a loopback address.

When I try to install it doesn't recognise a wireless network drive or `wlan0`.

wlan0 does not exist.

I used the command `lspci`

My Network Card is:

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Rev03
```

When I run `airmon-ng` command it doesn't show any interfaces at all. I can't even see the option in the network manager to choose wireless connection.

Comment: Have you try ifconfig -a?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing drivers and firmware. Some Linux distro's do not include all drivers, specially not for wireless. I am not sure but I think the modules are provided in `broadcom-sta-dkms`

Comment: You are right the support for the BCM4352 are provided by broadcom-sta-dkms http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali/dists/kali-rolling/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages

Answer (score 0):

To confirm, you do have a eth0? If so. I highly suggest making sure your linux distro is pointed at the new(ish) Repo's https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories and then make sure you can hit the internet through eth0 and run a full apt-get update. Reboot and try again. If that doesn't bring up the wireless NIC, there is a bigger issue. That broadcom NIC is pretty standard, so it should show up.

It is possible for OS images to get corrupted. Not common, but is a thing. I'd trouble shoot first with a lightweight distro like Lubuntu. Live boot that and see if wlan0 comes up. If so, try a fresh Kali image and copy the settings from lubuntu as they are pretty similar OS. If none of that works there is most likely a hardware issue.  Also, don't forget a couple things:

Putting your wifi nic into Mon mode using airmon-ng and other things shuts off the network manager (most of time, depends on how you do it). So if it ever worked and you're doing some wifi cracking, that could be your problem. Also don't forget about:

iwconfig -a

Good luck, let us know if any of the above works.